# Flutter how to manage user memberhip plan for UI?

Tags: flutter

In my case, I have an app which it contains 3 user membership type. I know I'm gonna implement the app purchase but that's not what i mean. Let's take a look at the example.

We got 3 memberhsip. `Bronze, Gold and Premium.` Let's say someone bought Gold membership. And I want to give him *`access to all Bronze and Gold's features`* and don't allow for `*Premium's features*`.

This logic is new for me. How can I handle with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply manage the user role enum on your app side and while using the app every user will have one of the enum cases as current membership.

According to that enum, you can hide/show or grant access to the features in the application.

So for example your enum will be as below.

```
enum MemberShips {
  gold, 
  premium, 
  broze, 
  none// by default
}
```

By using the above enum you can manage visibility and access to features and functionality in your application.

Let me know if you need more information or understanding on the same.

Comment: Wish you good sunday sir. I already thought create a enum cases. Actually, I wondering  about how can I give access to user in whole app. I mean I don't want to do if else every widget, button func. e.g.  Let's assume that we have 1 screen. In that screen we have 4 button which it's doing some backend stuff. But if Im gold i can't reach 3 button. In this situation, I don't want to check if user ==gold e.g. condition for each button. It will be a spaghetti code.

Comment: When I think about in MaterialApp level, I can use if else or use switch condition like if(user==gold). But in this case, I think I have to create pages for each user. I mean page for gold user, page for bronze user.. Ummm.. that's annoying.

Comment: You don't need to compare the ```user == gold ``` everywhere you can create the single getter in common classes like isGold, isBronz, and isPaltinum, and using this parameter anyways you have to hide or show the feature or button. 

Other wise you can create a separate screen/module user wise but it will be repateative code for you which is not right approach at all.